# Javascript Intl - How to get all timezones with abbrivation and offset

Tags: javascript

Any standard method in javascript which can get timezone abbreviation and offset using `Intl`?

`Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')` gets all timezones. How can I get timezone abbreviation and offset along with timezone. For eg., I need to get `PDT / PST` abbreviation, offset `UTC−07:00` for the timezone  `America/Los_Angeles`

Comment: [Quite a few native suggestions here](https://www.google.com/search?q=get+timezone+short+name+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 5):

Using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` able to get timezone abbreviation and offset. Below snippet gets timezone with abbreviation and offset.

```js
const timezonesWithoffsets =  Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone').map(timeZone => {
  const offset=new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en',{timeZone:timeZone, timeZoneName:'shortOffset'}).formatToParts().find(part => part.type==='timeZoneName').value
  const timeZoneAbbrivation = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en',{timeZone:timeZone, timeZoneName:'long'}).formatToParts().find(part => part.type==='timeZoneName').value
  return `${timeZone} - ${timeZoneAbbrivation}(${offset})`
}) 

console.log(timezonesWithoffsets)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using the [`formatToParts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) function, you can get the abbreviation and offset using the 'short' and 'longOffset' components.

```js
function getAbbreviation(timeZone) {
    return getFormattedElement(timeZone, 'timeZoneName', 'short')
}

function getOffset(timeZone) {
    return getFormattedElement(timeZone, 'timeZoneName', 'longOffset')
}

function getFormattedElement(timeZone, name, value) {
    return (new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
        [name]: value,
        timeZone 
    }).formatToParts().find(el => el.type === name) || {}).value;
}

console.log('Abbreviation:', getAbbreviation('America/Los_Angeles'));
console.log('Offset:', getOffset('America/Los_Angeles'));
```

Note that this gives offsets in the format `GMT(+|-)...`, not `UTC(+|-)...` — this can be easily fixed by using `getOffset(timeZone).replace('GMT', 'UTC')`.

In addition, `Intl.DateTimeFormat#formatToParts` uses the current system time as a default if no parameter is supplied, which means the offset is scoped to the current date (i.e. taking daylight-savings into account). If the offset as of a different date is required, you could allow supplying additional parameters:

```js
function getFormattedElement(timeZone, name, value, ...dateParams) {
    return (new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
        [name]: value,
        timeZone,
    }).formatToParts(new Date(...dateParams)).find(el => el.type === name) || {}).value;
}

for (const year of [2022, 2023]) {
    console.log(`Europe/London, Mar 26, ${year}:`, getFormattedElement('Europe/London', 'timeZoneName', 'longOffset', `${year}-03-26T12:00:00Z`));
}
```

---

Also worth looking at [`tzdb`](https://github.com/vvo/tzdb), this maintains a list of detailed timezone information, including offset, abbreviation etc.

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script type="module">

import { getTimeZones } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@vvo/tzdb'

const timeZones = getTimeZones();

function minutesToHHMM(minutes) {
    const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    const mins = Math.abs(minutes % 60);
    return (hours < 0 ? '-': '+') + (Math.abs(hours) + '').padStart(2, '0') + ':' + (mins + '').padStart(2, '0')
}

function getTimezoneDetails(tz) {
    const currentOffsetMinutes = tz.currentTimeOffsetInMinutes;
    const currentOffset = 'UTC' + minutesToHHMM(currentOffsetMinutes);
    return { name: tz.name, currentOffsetMinutes, currentOffset, abbreviation: tz.abbreviation }
}

console.log(timeZones.map(getTimezoneDetails))

</script>
```

---

As a side note, 3-letter time-zone IDs, such as `PST`, should be considered deprecated for most purposes, as many of them are ambiguous. See for example `CST`, which can refer to [3 completely different time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CST#Time_zones).

Comment: `timeZoneName` short gives 'PST' or 'GMT', so used long.